# Cannot open file in Spyder editor; only getting linux error: setNativeLocks failed: "No locks available"

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to access my files on the Spyder 3.2.8 editor, but any time I double-click on the file the editor freezes and I can't navigate it. Meanwhile, the error: setNativeLocks failed: "No locks available" continuously pops up in the Linux terminal I open Spyder with.

For some context, I did recently update from version 3.1.4 to 3.2.8. I also mainly use my own environment I created in anaconda, but the result is the same inside or outside the environment. I've reinstalled/reset spyder, and restarted my computer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, I would not know if it works but I also use spyder with the version of 3.5. Ever thought of upgrading to it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do with the version because the problem occurred before updating to 3.2.8. Oddly enough, other students in my class are not having the same issue even using the same version and their own conda environments.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) about this. It looks like a bug, so that's the proper place to keep talking about this.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba Will do. Thank you.